# Aborting a computation correctly in .NETLink to allow future computations

Tags: .netlink

Has anyone had any success using the `AbortEvaluation()` function in `IKernelLink` to stop a computation and then do more computation and retrieve results?
I've managed to find the jlink sample and some description on how to set it up; Put`Evaluate` and `WaitForAnswer()` on one thread, and call `AbortEvaluation()` from another. The following is a sample code that I'm written according to the description:

```
        var mlink = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                mlink.Evaluate("Do[2+2, {200000000}]");
                Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for Result...");
                mlink.WaitForAnswer();
            }
        );

        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
                st.Start();
                while (!t.IsCompleted)
                {
                    if (st.ElapsedMilliseconds > 100)
                    {
                        mlink.AbortEvaluation();
                        Debug.WriteLine("Action Aborted");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                st.Stop();
            }
        );

        Task.WaitAll(new Task[] {t});

        Debug.WriteLine("Result = " + mlink.GetString());
        mlink.Evaluate("1 + 1");
        mlink.WaitForAnswer();
        Debug.WriteLine("1 + 1 = " + mlink.GetString());
        mlink.Evaluate("2 + 2");
        mlink.WaitForAnswer();
        Debug.WriteLine("2 + 2 = " + mlink.GetString());
        mlink.Evaluate("4 + 4");
        mlink.WaitForAnswer();
        Debug.WriteLine("4 + 4 = " + mlink.GetString());
        mlink.Close();
```

Output is: 
Waiting for Result...,
Action Aborted,
Result = In[1]:= ,
1 + 1 = Null,
2 + 2 = 2,
4 + 4 = 4

I've tried the class `MathKernel` as well which results in the same problem where the results are shifted off (considering the implementation of `MathKernel` uses `IKernelLink` this is to be expected). Several other attempts has resulted in MLGet out of sequence errors or attempt to read protected memory.

---

EDIT:
Nevermind, I forgot to discard the initial packet. 
Simply add the line `mlink.WaitAndDiscard()` at after `CreateKernelLink();` for it to work.
MathKernel abort works as well. Trick appears to be launching them in two separate threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See edit at the bottom for faster solution.

To get this working in an actual implementation there are a few things to note, as it took me a lot more effort to get it from the prototype to the implementation.

- The Abort method simply causes `IKernelLink.WaitForAnswer()` to return straight away with the result "$Aborted".
- When using the `MathKernel.Compute()` method, make sure to allow it to run to completion. If you use something like the AbortableBackgroundWorker's abort method which terminates the thread immediately, it'll cause your MathKernel to end up in a corrupted state. This is because the `Compute` will call GetString() (or one of the many gets) after `WaitForAnswer()`. Missing the GetString() by terminating the thread means any further computation will give you a result of the previous computation.
- MLGet Out of Sequence error often means you're using the wrong Get function of `IKernelLink`. Try using `GetExpr` or `GetNextExpressionType` to see what you're fetching - not everything can be directly converted to a string.
- You will need a minimum of two threads (one can be the UI thread). One for compute, one for abort.
- A lock or check is recommended so you don't run more than one compute/evaluate at any given time.

EDIT:
Finally found a definite simple solution.
If `MathKernel.Abort()` is called, simply call `MathKernel.Link.Flush()` after, to clean out any lingering messages. You can then continue any computes as required and the .Result will be consistent.